# How to stop docker under Linux

Tags: docker, daemon

My version of OS `Ubuntu 16.04`.
I want to stop docker, so I run in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

But this commands doesn't help me:

```
gridsim1103 ~: ps ax | grep docker 
11347 ?        Sl     0:00 containerd-shim 487e3784f983274131d37bde1641db657e76e41bdd056f43ef4ad5adc1bfc518 /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/487e3784f983274131d37bde1641db657e76e41bdd056f43ef4ad5adc1bfc518 runc
14299 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto docker
29914 ?        S      0:00 sudo dockerd -H gridsim1103:2376
29915 ?        Sl     4:45 dockerd -H gridsim1103:2376
29922 ?        Ssl    0:24 containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --shim containerd-shim --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --runtime runc
30107 ?        Sl     1:01 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 188.184.80.77 -host-port 8500 -container-ip 192.17.0.2 -container-port 8500
30139 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 188.184.80.77 -host-port 8400 -container-ip 192.17.0.2 -container-port 8400
```

Version of `docker` server is:

```
Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24 (minimum version )
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Tue, 27 Sep 2016 12:25:38 +1300
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I also unsuccessfully tried:

```
 sudo service docker stop
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The output of `ps aux` looks like you did not start docker through systemd/systemctl.

It looks like you started it with:

```
sudo dockerd -H gridsim1103:2376
```

When you try to stop it with systemctl, nothing should happen as the resulting dockerd process is not controlled by systemd. So the behavior you see is expected.

The correct way to start docker is to use systemd/systemctl:

```
systemctl enable docker
systemctl start docker
```

After this, docker should start on system start.

EDIT: As you already have the docker process running, simply kill it by pressing CTRL+C on the terminal you started it. Or send a kill signal to the process.

Answer (score 130):

First I stop the docker by the following command:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

Then I get the message :`Warning: Stopping docker.service, but it can still be activated by:   docker.socket`.
So, I stop the socket as well :

```
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
```

Note: you can start and stop only the `docker.socket` when it triggers by it.

Answer (score 57):

In my case, it was neither systemd nor a cron job, but it was snap.
So I had to run:

```
sudo snap stop docker
sudo snap remove docker
```

... and the last command actually never ended, I don't know why: this snap thing is really a pain. So I also ran:

```
sudo apt purge snap
```

:-)

Comment: This is very useful, my dokerd process was taking 200% CPU but now it's more quiet now. Thanks!

Comment: You may use `sudo snap disable docker` so docker won't start next time you boot. In this case, yo use docker you'd need to run `sudo snap start docker`

Comment: the last command is good for machines having HDD, lol

Answer (score 33):

if you have ***no systemctl*** and started the docker daemon by:

```
sudo service docker start
```

you can stop it by:

```
sudo service docker stop
```

Comment: after running the stop command I got this : `Warning: Stopping docker.service, but it can still be activated by:
  docker.socket
`

Answer (score -10):

stop docker:

```
docker stop docker_id
```

ex:

```
docker stop 1fec077018w4
```

remove docker:

```
docker rm docker_id
```

ex:

```
docker rm 1fec077018w4
```

do not to stop:

```
docker-compose kill -s SIGINT
```

docker restart:

```
docker-compose restart
```