# How to stop Docker Engine

Tags: docker

I am new to docker. So for learning I install docker desktop for windows.

Everything is working fine and as soon as I clicked docker desktop app, I was able to execute docker command on my command prompt.

But when I closed my command prompt and opened it again, docker commands were still running. Then I closed docker desktop app but docker commands were still running on command prompt.

How can I close this connection between docker desktop app and my command prompt.

Comment: we need to know what command you have entered and still running, Anyway from powershell `wsl --shutdown` should stop docker permanently but its not recommended as there is a better solution for sure.

Comment: Right click the docker icon next to the clock... You can finish it off there

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to docker too, and I'm using linux not windows so I'm not sure how much of this will be applicable to you, but that said I've found the following:

1. To List running containers enter the command `docker ps`. You can then stop individual containers with `docker stop <CONTAINER ID>`. *Container ID will be listed when you run docker ps.*
2. If you want to then destroy the container completely you can enter the command `docker rm <CONTAINER ID>`.

I'm not sure how to stop the docker *server* on Windows but on Linux running systemd you do `sudo systemctl stop docker` [I found that info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718451/2204663)